# Display directory files in Internet Explorer window

Tags: vb.net

Similar to an FTP file listing in a browser window, is there a way in VB.NET to open a network directory in Internet Explorer, rather than File Explorer?

I will have a GPO that should prevent basic users from accessing File Explorer directly but the vb app they will use needs to return a directory listing, and I'd like to use Internet Explorer for that.